# pdfbox Ant build fails for .NET

Tags: pdfbox

I am attempting to build a .NET version of pdfbox with Ant. The build fails with the following error message:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox\build.xml:200: srcdir "C:\Program Files\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox-1.5.0\fontbox\src\main\java" does not exist!

Thanks for any help a java developer can give me. Since I'm not a java developer at all, non-cryptic, verbose answers REALLY appreciated.

Clyde

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't downloaded the entire source code of PDFBox. It includes companion packages Fontbox and Jempbox, the source of which are outside of the PDFBox folder. Given the paths above, you should have the following folders (among others):

C:\Program Files\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox...
C:\Program Files\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox-1.5.0\fontbox...
C:\Program Files\pdfbox-1.5.0\pdfbox-1.5.0\jempbox...

Under each of these folders, there should be a src\main\java... folder structure. If these don't exist, then you've unpackaged the source tar incorrectly, and the build script will fail because it can't find the files that it requires.

I've also found cases where the build script doesn't like spaces in path names, so it might be easier to unzip the source tree to c:\pdfbox... or something.